# Trying to use an SPWeb object that has been closed or disposed and is no longer valid.

Tags: ssom, spaudit, spauditeventtype

Can any one let me know what's the issue in my below code and how can I solve this

```
SPSite mysiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);
         SPWeb web = mysiteCollection.OpenWeb();
         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         SPAuditQuery query = new SPAuditQuery(mysiteCollection);
                   query.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
                   query.SetRangeEnd(DateTime.Now);
                   SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = mysiteCollection.Audit.GetEntries(query);

                   int i = 0;
                   foreach (SPAuditEntry entry in auditCol)
                   {
                       if (entry.Event == SPAuditEventType.Update)
                       {

                           GridView1.DataSource = entry.EventName;
                           GridView1.DataBind();

                       }
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
 using (SPSite mysiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
 {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = mysiteCollection.OpenWeb())
        {
             SPAuditQuery query = new SPAuditQuery(mysiteCollection);
             query.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
             query.SetRangeEnd(DateTime.Now);
             SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = mysiteCollection.Audit.GetEntries(query);

             DataTable dtAudit = new DataTable();
             dtAudit.Columns.Add("NewColumn", typeof(System.String));
             dtAudit.Columns.Add("NewColumnTwo", typeof(System.String));

             foreach (SPAuditEntry entry in auditCol)
             {
                  if (entry.Event == SPAuditEventType.Update)
                  {
                      DataRow dRow = dtAudit.Rows.Add();

                      dRow["NewColumn"] = entry.MachineName;
                      //dRow["NewColumnTwo"] = "TEXT";

                      dtAudit.Rows.Add(dRow);
                  }
              }

              GridView1.DataSource = dtAudit;
              GridView1.DataBind();
        }
  }
```